# cannot to create flutter in Android studio

Tags: android

I've tried doing the steps to build flutter correctly, but after that it gets stuck on loading, am I missing something?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVLHK.png)

The correct way to make a fluteer in Android Studio version 2022.3.1 Patch 3

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so other can answer. and if you sync project first time it takes time to load.